# Not able to select any other column except the first 1 in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Searched alot on the internet to understand the issue. Tried most of it but in vain. I am reading a tsv file which is tab delimited.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('abc.tsv',delimiter="\t", engine="python", encoding="UTF-8")
```

When I print the columns, I am getting this:

```
Index(['date', '​time', '​user_id', '​url', '​IP'], dtype='object')
```

When trying to access the dataframe, I am able to select only the first column by name while the rest gives KeyError:

```
print(df.loc[:, "time"])

KeyError: 'the label [time] is not in the [columns]'
```

Upgraded pandas also:

```
Successfully installed numpy-1.14.0 pandas-0.22.0 python-dateutil-2.6.1 pytz-2017.3 six-1.11.0
```

Any help would be highly appreciated

EDIT:

I can access all the columns with iloc

```
print(df.iloc[:, 1])
```

Comment: What return `print (df.columns.tolist())` ?

Comment: I think separator is `,` so need `df = pd.read_csv('abc.tsv',sep=",", engine="python", encoding="UTF-8")`

Comment: Or only `df = pd.read_csv('abc.tsv', encoding="UTF-8")`

Comment: @jezrael: columns.tolist() solved it. Apparently there are zero width space in the column name. ['date', '\u200btime', '\u200buser_id', '\u200burl', '\u200bIP']. Could you please tell which parameter should i use to remove this. I know about skipinitialspace, but I don't think that would be of any use in this case

Comment: Use `df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()` if `skipinitialspace=True` does not work.

Comment: @jezrael: 'df.columns = df.columns.str.strip("\u200b")' worked. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comments to answer:

If return:

```
print (df.columns.tolist())

['date', '\u200btime', '\u200buser_id', '\u200burl', '\u200bIP']
```

then use `strip` for remove trailing whitespaces:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()
```

In this particular case, it was :

`df.columns = df.columns.str.strip("\u200b")`